# Is it possible to match an image with its appearance in a video?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a short video of 10 mins. This video is actually an online lecture. When you watch it, you will only see slide show (some slides are annotated).

I have the original slides (pdf or image or ppt or whatever). Is it possible to match each slide with a specific time in video when it appears?

My idea is to take every image and compare it with every video frames of that video and try to match the slide image in video.

How do you think my idea? Is it possible and doable with some algorithm?Can I just substract the video frame with the image (calculate the difference) to see which difference is close to zero? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are perfectly aligned, then you can use any of simple differencing, sum of squared differences or normalised cross-correlation. However, if they are not aligned, you will need to register the two images first, followed by any of the three mentioned matching methods. Do a google search for image registration. Affine registration might be sufficient for your problem.

Comment: thanks for the information. OpenCV can do image registration, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but affine registration is relatively simple to implement. You can take a look at this report as a reference: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70092/tr-2004-92.pdf

Comment: thanks. Do you think simply doing template matching will work as well? I don't think the slide shown in video is much distorted.

Comment: Does it scale, translate or rotate at all? If not, then template matching will do. Even with translation but without scale change or rotation, you can do template matching with shifts in x and y.